# Get Netbeans to recognize Python methods

Tags: python, autocomplete, netbeans-8

I was just wondering if there was a way to get Python (in Netbeans) to recognize the methods that I write in a class. For example when I do `self.method()` I just want Netbeans to recognize it's a method in the class I am currently in. Does Netbeans 8.0 Python IDE not support that right now, or is there something I can do to make Netbeans recognize them?

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins available in netbeans plugin portal from which you can download and install them to your netbeans. Here is a link: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/61688/python
These will support minimal editing, building, debugging.
These are also available in Netbeans plugin menu. You can also download it from there!